# What is this Windows icon used for?

Tags: windows-11, icons

I am browsing *imageresdll.mun* file<sup>1</sup> using Resource Hacker 5.1.7. All icons seems familiar and clearly denotes usage. Except this one:

[image]

What service, software or hardware is this icon used for?

<sup>1</sup> <sub>on Windows 10 and 11 they've moved icons out of *shell32.dll* and *imageres.dll* to their .mun counterparts.</sub>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on @DavidPostill 's answer, the icon featured within the folder is a more modern version of the [link symbol](https://unicode-table.com/en/1F517/).  This implies the folder contains links, hence "Folder Links".  This is likely intended for use by `explorer.exe` when assigning custom folder icons, and likely was intended for the `Links` directory (related [reference](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/what-is-the-links-folder-for/c55ec751-5997-4193-8910-bbae99ec66ea)).

Answer (score 3):

#### What service, software or hardware does this icon is used for?

A reverse google image search leads to [Folder Links Icon](http://www.rw-designer.com/icon-detail/22974):

> **Folder Links.ico**
>
> - Published on August 20th 2021 by ♠♣♥♦Liyan Graphicsツ.
> - Released under the Release to Public Domain license.
> - Icon for Windows XP, Vista and 7.

The "256x256 pixels, 68 bits per pixel" icon in that set is the icon from your question:

[image]